# Why aren't exact differential equations considered PDE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Exact differential equations come from finding the total differential from some multivariable function.

In the exact differential equation $M\mathrm{d}x+N\mathrm{d}y=0$

M and N are considered to be partial derivatives of some potential function... So why aren't exact differential equations considered PDEs? After all, you're finding the potential function given it's partial derivatives...

Thanks.

Comment: Because it is essentially a differential equation $dF(x(t),y(t))/dt=0$.

Comment: But it's not always the case that both x and y are functions of t. Or is this irrelevant?

Comment: It has to be, $x,y$ are functionally dependent. If you don't like $t$, how about $x$?

Comment: No no, I'm not against the letter t. I'm just saying that x and y are not always functions of the same variable. Or do they have to be? How do you know they have to be?

Comment: Since $Mdx+Ndy$ is exact, it has a primitive $F(x,y)$. So $Mdx+Ndy=0$ means $F(x,y)=c$ a constant. This is a level set or simply a curve in $\mathbb R^2$. So a curve can always be parametrized. You could just check up implicit function theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Because the partial differentials part is just a method of solving them, it's in the intermediate steps of a solution, not in the DE itself from the start. A bad example(can't think of a better one right now) would be considering $x-2=0$ a second degree polynomial because you can introduce parameters and make it $x^2=4, x>0$.

Also, consider being able to solve a D.E. by transforming it into exact equation by multiplying it with an integrating factor or by using another method that has nothing to do with partial derivatives. Why would you call that a PDE?

A more specialized example would be $$y'=y \iff y'-y=0 \stackrel{\cdot e^{-x}}{\iff}\frac{y'}{e^x}-\frac{y}{e^x}=0$$
Now, would you consider $y'=y$ a PDE?